# How do I modify css of the any element on the page when an element is active using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a div and an input inside the div.

```
<div id="div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search"/>
</div>
```

When the input is active I want #div to be affected.
Something like this:

```
#div input:active -> affect #div{
    background:white;
}
```

There is questions similar to this but they are for objects inside input or whatever div.

Thanks in advance.